# Connecting to Cassandra 2.0 from .NET Driver

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-ec2, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I'm fairly new to Cassandra, and have recently implemented a 2-node cluster on Amazon EC2.  I have the 2 data nodes, and 1 application server (running .NET 4.0, connecting to the data nodes through the Cassandra driver), all in the same Amazon availability zone.

After a whole lot of tweaking of the security group, I was finally able to get the connection to work by creating an inbound rule on each of the data nodes to allow ALL TCP traffic from the application server.  I don't think this is particularly ideal security-wise, even though I don't see it as a huge risk especially since I'm using private IPs.

My question is this, what port is used for the connection between a .NET Cassandra driver, and the cluster?  Based on the documentation, I thought that's what the 9160 RPC port was all about, but when I created a rule for that it didn't seem to do anything.  I also tried 7199 and 9042 (just based on little tid bits I've found scattered on the internet).

Thanks, 
Todd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be whatever is configured on your `cassandra-env.sh` file.  As per the docs:

http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/FAQ#ports

Having said if you look at the .NET driver for Cassandra (C#) in the file `Cassandra/Cluster.cs` it mentions that default from the driver is `9042`. You can see the file here: https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver/blob/1.0/Cassandra/Cluster.cs . Also, this is the excerpt that shows the default port:

```
/// <summary>
///  The port to use to connect to the Cassandra host. If not set through this
///  method, the default port (9042) will be used instead.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="port"> the port to set. </param>
///
/// <returns>this Builder</returns>
public Builder WithPort(int port)
{
    this._port = port;
    return this;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That seemed to do it!  I know I tried 9042 at one time in the past, but I think I had other configuration issues at the time so it was probably a bad test.  Thanks for the insight.